# Achieving a more generic approach to my function in Swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift, nspredicate, xcode6

I have an array in Swift that holds the number of shifts you've worked for the work week.
I would like to retrieve the first element from this collection that matches on a particular condition (in this case date worked).

Later, however, I may also want to find other things such as your highest earning shift. I might even want to select all items that match a particular clause instead of just one.

Are predicates involved here in doing something like this generically? Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or share some code examples that could help me achieve this so I don't have to write multiple functions for a specific purpose on an array?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is simply to use `indexOfObjectPassingTest` and the correct predicate. This is effective when you want to do a small number of unique searches on a small array, where it's next to useless to abstract each type of search in its own function.
However:

- if you have the same search made in multiple places in your code, consider abstracting the code into functions and even its own class
- if you have a very large array and if the predicates can be very complex, consider CoreData or another database solution. You'll be better off in the long run.
- if you need large result sets, also consider CoreData/databases

Comment: Thank you. Can the filter function be used here?

Comment: Sure, as well as `indexesOfObject`. But your decision depends on the size of the original array, the complexity of the contained objects, the complexity of the predicates, the size of the result set, etc...

Comment: array size will always be 7

Comment: Too small for CoreData. Use an array and predicates, including `index(es)OfObject` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this what do you think?   shiftsForDay = shifts.filter{$0.shiftDate == self.chosenDate}   I figured since it's one line, I can just do this and not be generic about it filter is good enough.

Comment: Sure. For a 7-item array you don't want anything more complicated.